# Custom Font not working on Firefox and IE. Chrome Fine

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts

Recently I used a custom font on my websites. After uploading it to a server, I was only able to view the font in Google Chrome. In Firefox and IE, the font switched back to Times New Romans. However, after uploading it to another server, both FF and Chrome can view it but IE still can't. Is there any way to ensure that all browsers can use the font?

Answer (score 0):

`Make sure your @font-face rule like below`

```
    @font-face {
     font-family: "Calibri";
     src: url('fonts/calibri_2.eot');
     src: url('fonts/calibri_2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/calibri_2.svg#Calibri') format('svg'),
     url('fonts/calibri_2.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/calibri_2.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
```